# How to emit event in promise resolved in Angular2+

Tags: angular, events, eventemitter

I have below code

```
this.expenseClaimService.saveExpenseItem(this.item)
      .then((data) => {
          Object.assign(this.item, data);
          console.log('saveExpenseItem.then', data);
          this.onCategorySelected.emit();
        });
      });
```

which I emit event when the promise is resolved,

The problem is the event handler doesn't catch the event.

If I emit same event in code (not it promise resolve) it works fine, which means everything is wired up correctly.

### Update (solved)

I found what was wrong, I had the component in ngIf, in the time my promise was resolved value was changed in a way the ngIf become false and then component was destroyed, and there were no observer for that event anymore. so I changed it to `hidden` and now it works.

```
<div *ngIf="this.item" [hidden]="this.item.ExpenseCategoryId != null">
  <app-expense-item-category-selector [item]="item" (onCategorySelected)="onCategorySelected($event)"></app-expense-item-category-selector>
</div>
```

I keep the question and I don't delete it in case somebody else has same issue

Comment: Seems to be a matter of scope. Have you tried to put the emission-call into a local method and call this method instead?

Comment: What does your subscriber look like? Is it in the same component or service or elsewhere? How do you find it and when?

Comment: @Zlatko `<app-expense-item-category-selector [item]="item" (onCategorySelected)="onCategorySelected()"`

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the service-call happens in the child component I'd suggest the following to avoid scope driven problems:

```
aMethod(){
  this.expenseClaimService.saveExpenseItem(this.item)
    .then((data) => {
       console.log('saveExpenseItem.then', data);
       this.doEmit();
     });
   });
}

private doEmit(){
   this.onCategorySelected.emit();
}
```